# Updating project with my changes and other changes with TortoiseHg

Tags: version-control, tortoisehg

Let's say I have repo A, the main branch. I clone repo A into repo B, in repo B I make changes to it over a period of time. Then I decide to clone repo A again into repo C, it has what repo A has plus changes that other users have made over time. Using TortoiseHg, how can I can combine repo B and C so I can push them into repo A?

Pardon me if my vocabulary isn't that good with the title or description, it's the best way I could describe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pull (B->C or C->B direction):

- you have to know URL of "foreign" repo
- you have to enable web-server on "foreign" repo (if it's remote repository not on local filesystem)
- you have to add URL of "foreign" repo into local's repo configuration (using GUI - Sync dialogue or by adding new external repo into `[paths]` section of repository's .hgrc) or fastest way is to pull from console (one-time operation, yes?), using URL of foreign repo in `hg pull URL` command

As result you'll get diverged history at some point, which you have to merge in order to push later without errors|warnings or `--force` pushes

I'm too lazy to show screenshots for such easy task, but I can, if it's really needed